# root password error

Tags: apt, updates, sudo

I am new to this OS. I am installing my own LAMP stack via terminal.
I followed the instruction given in you-tube on how to install LAMP stack using terminal.

here it goes

I type in

```
sudo apt-get update
```

then asking my password. at first I thought it is my account password which I used before entering my desktop. after I use my account password it gave an error "sorry not password"... can you please help me I want to learn solve this problem and learn PHP using this OS..thank you in advance

Comment: please run `id -Gn` in your terminal and post the results into your question!

Answer (score -1):

You can download xampp also for linux  use these commands for install 
go on this url click on linux version.
    https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html

1.Change the permissionwith this command

```
sudo chmod +x xampp-linux-x64-5.6.3-0-installer.run
```

run xampp with this command

```
sudo ./xampp-linux-x64-5.6.3-0-installer.run
```

after once xampp install everytime you dont need to run above command for start  you can use this command for start all service

```
sudo /opt/lampp/lampp start
```

Comment: `sudo` is not needed for the `chmod` command if you are running it as the same user who downloaded the file. I would also discourage running XAMPP as root (`sudo` in the last command).

Comment: I would discourage using XAMPP. Period. We have a native stack that works out of the box.